# Symfony's annotations ignored by firewall

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, yaml

I have a `AccountController.php` file in Symfony 2.6.6 that works with [annotations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html):

```php
<?php

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

/**
 * @Route("/login", name="account_login")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request) {}

/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="account_login_check")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
public function loginCheckAction() {}

/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="account_logout")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function logoutAction() {}

/**
 * @Route("/register", name="account_register")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function registerAction(Request $request) {}
```

My access_control in the firewall:

```yaml
access_control:
    - { path: ^/account/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/account/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/account/logout, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED }
```

I tried using `@Security("has_role('is_authenticated')")` on the logoutAction but when I am not logged in (anon.) it still lets me go to the page.

Is there a way to lock a function with a @Security on the right way? Is my firewall even needed when I am using annotations?

Thanks.

Comment: which version of symfony2?

Comment: I am sorry I did not include the version number. I edited my post. It is 2.6.6.

Comment: try IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED instead of IS_AUTHENTICATED

Comment: Just checking the obvious - your `access_control` says `^/account/logout` but your URL only says `/logout`. You are prepending that `/account` bit in the routing somewhere else, right?

Comment: Oops, yes. It is above the class Account as `@Route("/account")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
- { path: ^/account/logout, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```